# How to update an Array within a document using bulk.find().updateOne()

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection of Vendors and each vendor has an Array of Categories [**vendor_category**]. I'm trying to update the name and slug of each Category where the category _id matched. I am using a UnorderedBulkOp to loop through the collection.

```
[{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "64663f4ec3560b33e85dd07d"
  },
  "featured": "no",
  "protocol": "http://",
  "vendor_category": [
    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "646515f6a120635ddce14e7d"
      },
      "name": "News Articles",
      "slug": "news-articles",
      "status": "active",
      "created_ts": "2023-05-17T17:59:18.635Z"
    },
    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "64679a1af8a58923f84c8ffb"
      },
      "name": "Guardian Groups",
      "slug": "guardian-groups",
      "status": "active",
      "created_ts": "2023-05-19T15:47:38.867Z"
    }
  ],
  "name": "Assumenda dolor nobi"
}]
```

Here is the code I tried to execute I get no error when I try to execute the code and no changes are made:

```
let arr = results.map(e => e._id)

      const bulkOp = Facility.db.initializeUnorderedBulkOp()

      for (let a = 0; a < arr.length; a++) {
        bulkOp.find({'_id': mongojs.ObjectId(arr[a])}) // a = 64663f4ec3560b33e85dd07d
          .updateOne({$set: { 'vendor_category.$.name': req.body.name, 'vendor_category.$.slug': req.body.slug }}, { upsert: true })
      }

      bulkOp.execute()
```

I'm trying to update specific fields, (I removed the 's' from the name Guardian Group and the slug)  See my desired output:

```
[{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "64663f4ec3560b33e85dd07d"
  },
  "featured": "no",
  "protocol": "http://",
  "vendor_category": [
    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "646515f6a120635ddce14e7d"
      },
      "name": "News Articles",
      "slug": "news-articles",
      "status": "active",
      "created_ts": "2023-05-17T17:59:18.635Z"
    },
    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "64679a1af8a58923f84c8ffb"
      },
      "name": "Guardian Group",
      "slug": "guardian-group",
      "status": "active",
      "created_ts": "2023-05-19T15:47:38.867Z"
    }
  ],
  "name": "Assumenda dolor nobi"
}]
```

Comment: Can you mention what issue are you facing while running your code? Do you see error or it does something unexpected?

Comment: Sorry @Kartoos I get no error and no update is made.